# Is dmp file suitable despite ORA-01555 'snapshop too old' warnings?

Tags: oracle, import, export, dump

Well, the title of the question is self-explanatory.

- Export finished successfully **with warnings**.
- Log shows several ORA-01555 snapshot too old errors.

**- Is it OK to use that dmp file to perform an import full in another instance?**

**- Would running the export in restricted mode (no users connected) garantee no 'ORA-01555 snapshot too old' would occur?**

Comment: Mostly this error occurs when caused by Oracle read consistency mechanism.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan I know. Do you have an answer for my doubt about the dmp being suitable for an import full and whether or not the same error would occur if no user is connected?

Comment: What oracle version do you use? what kind of export tool do you user (exp or expdb)? can you publish your parameters that you use for the export?

Comment: @miracle173 8.1.7.0 (don't ask why, we are trying to migrate it to 9 then to 10) buffer=10240000 consistent=y full=y

Comment: you use `exp` because `exdp` does not exist for 8.1.7. The 'consistent=y' parameter means that the ["Export uses the SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY statement to ensure that the data seen by Export is consistent to a single point in time and does not change during the execution of the exp command."](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-74FB1C84-D8A2-40B7-B920-597B4D546F39.htm). So if you export some tables at a later point in time your data will not be conistent anymore. This may be a problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be time saving if you just backup the tables being errored in ORA-1555 after the warning full backups. 
Yes, to answer main question,  it is good backup to be imported,  you can exclude the errored tables or use table_exists_action=replace using tables only backup after taking the tables backup in above para.

Scenario warning = if the errored tables  have any dependent primary key or foreign key referenced  constraints, then the other tables being referenced also needs to be backed up maintaining consistency to make sure constraints don't get invalid.

Comment: Wouldn't the tables-only exports also contain ORA-01555?

Comment: It  depends on the transactions being in process on the tables and undo retention settings as mentioned in previous answer,  it's better to check them before tables backup it may throw error again.

Comment: You mean each table listed in the log just above the error don't get exported at all, not even partially?

Comment: No,  just the object being mentioned in the ora-1555 error is not exported. you can see the rows being exported for successful backups and for errored tables no such information is available.

Comment: I accepted this answer despite the downvotes because it answered what I wanted to know: the dump is not suitable for an import full because some tables that weren't exported at all, not even partially.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you could, but it is **incomplete**, so better repeat the export after performing the necessary actions to avoid ORA-01555 errors (have an appropriately sized undo tablespace, set `undo_retention` and `retention guarantee`).

Comment: That being incomplete means an import full would be unsuccessfull? Would there be problems with inconsistent SCNs and the such? Could the import full be suitable for time-estimation purposes? We are estimating how long the expor full and the import full would take. The day of the "real thing" no user will be connected during export and theoretically no ORA-01555 should occur that day because there are no transactions.

Comment: Please elaborate. Answer is too terse.